# Can I deactivate my CiviCRM WordPress plugin without losing all my data?

Tags: wordpress, data

We haven't used our CiviCRM plugin for quite some time, but it has acquired data I don't want to lose. I think it's slowing our site down and I'd like to disable it in anticipation of increased web traffic for an upcoming event. If I deactivate it, will I lose all my data?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE! If you deactivate the CiviCRM plugin the data will still all be in the database and not changed. However, I'd be surprised if CiviCRM slowed anything down if its not being used, so I think you'll have to look elsewhere for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a million! I'll give it a shot, at any rate, since deactivating it won't hurt anything.